# Why does Seaborn Countplot only count to 10 in a Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: pandas, seaborn

I have a DataFrame as this:

```
    Municipality     Category   Count
0   BECKENRIED       Rindvieh   374.0
1   BECKENRIED       Rindvieh   69.0
2   BECKENRIED       Rindvieh   1.0
3   BECKENRIED       Rindvieh   120.0
4   BECKENRIED       Rindvieh   5.0
... ... ... ...
346 WOLFENSCHIESSEN  Geflügel   7.0
347 WOLFENSCHIESSEN  Geflügel   5010.0
348 WOLFENSCHIESSEN  Andere     2.0
349 WOLFENSCHIESSEN  Andere     8.0
350 WOLFENSCHIESSEN  Andere     7.0
```

After grouping and suming over "Count" I find how many animals each municipality has:

```
nw_animals_2020.groupby(["Municipality", "Category"])["Count"].sum()
Municipality     Category
BECKENRIED       Andere        13.0
                 Equiden       15.0
                 Geflügel      75.0
                 Rindvieh     779.0
                 Schafe       259.0
                              ...  
WOLFENSCHIESSEN  Geflügel    5267.0
                 Rindvieh    1526.0
                 Schafe       470.0
                 Schweine     426.0
                 Ziegen       783.0
```

However, when using a `seaborn.countplot`, the sum is completely different and appears to be capped at 10:

```
g = sns.catplot(x="Gemeinde", hue="Gattung", data=nw_animals_2020, kind="count")
g.set_xticklabels(rotation=45)
```

[image]

What is the problem here?

Comment: `catplot(..., kind='count')` only counts the appearances, not sum as you want. So `Count=10000` only counts as `1`. You may want to do `barplot(..., dodge=True)`.

Comment: g = sns.barplot(x="Gemeinde", y="Massgebende Anzahl", hue="Gattung", data=nw_animals_2020_agg)